# What the decode function do in the update flag port in informatica?

Tags: decode, data-warehouse, etl, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I'm new to Informatica and like to ask a question regarding infa ports. I found an example which show how to create an update flag in expression transform for updating data. The code in `v_UPDATE_FLAG` port looks like this:

```
IIF(NOT ISNULL(PREV_ITEM_KEY)
AND
(
DECODE(BONUS_FLAG,PREV_BONUS_FLAG,1,0) = 0 
OR
DECODE(DISCOUNT,PREV_DISCOUNT,1,0) = 0 
OR
DECODE(PRICE,PREV_PRICE,1,0) = 0 
),'TRUE','FALSE')
```

Can you explain what this does? What the DECODE does here??

```
DECODE(BONUS_FLAG,PREV_BONUS_FLAG,1,0) = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DECODE` syntax:

```
DECODE (
  value
, first_search  , first_result 
, second_search , second_result
, ...           , ...
                , default
)
```

The `value` parameter is compared with the `search` parameters and, when the first match is found, a respective `result` parameter is returned. If there is no match, the `default` parameter is returned.

`DECODE(BONUS_FLAG,PREV_BONUS_FLAG,1,0) = 0` means that the `BONUS_FLAG` and `PREV_BONUS_FLAG` are not equal.

The entire expression flags a row for UPDATE when `PREV_ITEM_KEY` is not NULL and any of the attributes `BONUS_FLAG`, `DISCOUNT` or `PRICE` has changed (previous value versus current value).